# Выполнение Ajax callback после валидации формы Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal

У меня есть дефолтная форма контактов в Drupal 8, которую  я немного кастомизировал через hook_form_alter и добавил ajax запрос.

```
function helloworld_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

if ($form_id == 'contact_message_feedback_form') {

$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
  'wrapper' => 'form_wrapper',
  'callback' => 'custom_callback',
  'event' => 'click',
  'progress' => [
  'type' => 'throbber',
  'message' => 'Veryfieng'],
  );  

$form['test_selection'] = [
  '#type' => 'hidden', 
  '#prefix' => '<div id="form_wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#weight' => 100,
];
  }
} 



 function custom_callback($form, &$form_state) {
   $output = array();

   $output['#markup'] = 'Thank you! Your message has been sent!';

   return $output;
 }
```

Все работает, но проблема в том, что полностью игнорируется валидация. 
Как мне сделать так, чтобы валидация проходила до того как выполнится функция custom_callback?